# Django, deployment on Heroku. SMTPSenderRefused at /password_reset/ when i try to send an email

Tags: django, heroku, smtp

I'm deploying the Django app on Heroku. App works fine, but when I try to reset a forgotten password via sending an email - I encounter this error:

**SMTPSenderRefused at /password_reset/
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError h13sm1336757qti.32 - gsmtp', 'None')**

Also, it's only when i work with my Django app using Heroku server (something like **beautiful-flowers-12345.herokuapp.com**, i don't know), not localhost 127.0.0.1:8000. Sending an email when i work with my Django app using local host - works just fine, no any errors.

The only way to fix this error is to replace this:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

with this:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'fake_email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myfakepassword123'
```

and switch on permission to use less secure apps in Gmail settings.

**BUT THIS IS NOT HOW I WOULD LIKE TO SOLVE THIS**

1) i show my host_user and host_password with this approach, which i don't want.

2) each user needs to go here **"Gmail -> Settings -> Allow less secure apps"**, and i don't want that either, because it's not wery user friendly. Moreover, why should the user allow access to unsecure applications?

Maybe you have encountered this problem and know how to solve it in a different way? Thanks!

Comment: Have you set a ssl on the heroku app domain?

Comment: Well..probably, no. Can you tell me, how can i do that? This is my first time working with Heroku, I haven't hosted any websites there before, honestly. Thanks.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I just logged in, then created personal Heroku app and then i executed this command - git push heroku master. I didn't do anything else.

Comment: @Dimitry49921see my answer below for how to add environment variables in heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things to mention here:

1) You are absolutely right to not want to hard-code in your email and password, and they definitely should be stored as environment variables. You will have to set them slightly differently on heroku than how you have done in development though:

- go to your app in heroku
- click on settings
- There should be a section called config variables. Click 'reveal config vars'
- Here you can enter your config variables.

2) Not every user will need to set their Gmail to use less secure apps. This is only needed for the email account that is being used to **send** emails. (Presumably your users are just receiving emails).

Finally, it is worth knowing that I believe for gmail, this solution will not work for too much longer. (Again, all of what I'm about to say only applies to the email being used to send, not your users' emails). Google will be tightening up on 'less secure apps' and require use of OAuth. I think this was due to happen around June or July, but google might have pushed back on their deadline due to the covid-19 situation.

An alternative will be to use a service such as mailGun, which is virtually free for a small number of emails, and is very easy to integrate with your project. They have great docs. A library like django-anymail can also make integration with any number of email services very simple.

**EDIT:** It is also worth checking to see if any attempts on your google account have been blocked. When the attempt has been made from the heroku server, since that server is mostly likely in a different geographical location to where you are, google may well treat that attempt as suspicious, and block it. So it's worth checking this too.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for helping me, but i still getting this error...I created these config variables EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, and stored my 'fakemail123@gmail.com' and 'fakepassword123' values in it, as you said. I just don't know why this problem didn't solved.

Comment: Hmm... can you confirm it's working fine on your local setup. I've added an edit, to explain what might be happening rather than write it in these comments.

Comment: Thanks man! It's nothing,.. i'm just exremely stupid. I forgot that i use different name for my variables. It works fine! Dog bless you! :) I'm sorry I bothered you.